# Create a matrix made of matrices with different sizes

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to create a matrix which elements are matrices (with different sizes), vectors and numbers. 
For example, I have the next two matrices, one vector and one number:

```
A = [1 2 3
     4 5 6
     7 8 9]

B = [10 11
     12 13]

C = [14
     15
     16]

D = 17
```

And I would like to obtain a matrix 2x2, K, whith elements:
 `k_11 = A, k_12 = B, k_21 = C, k_22 = D`.

The idea is to have the possibility to choose matrices, vectors or numbers of the big matrix, K, like they would be "simple" elements of a matrix. I.e.:
`K[0,0] = A, K[0,1] = B` and so on.

Firstly, I thougth I could to obtain a list of matrices, vectors and numbers with `K.append(A)`..., but then I figured out that I will not be able to transform the list into a matrix.
And secondly, I tried to create a block matrix with `numpy.bmat`. The problem with `bmat` is that the dimensions of the inputs elements must match exactly.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You could place the smaller matrices as objects in a numpy array of type `object`...

Answer (score 2):

First, store the 4 objects in a 2D list, then make the list into a `numpy.matrix`.

```
K = matrix([[A, B], [C, D])
```

Comment: You might want to explain the `object` data type to round out your answer, noting the limitations, for example, won't be able to do matrix math on the object matrix.

Comment: Err, actually I am not sure about the *general* limitations of `object`. Here, it is clear that matrix math is not going to work (the elements have different shapes...). But is it always the case, regardless of what data is represented? Not trying to suggest anything, I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answers I created a 2D list but I did not use `numpy.matrix` because with the list I can choose the element of the "matrix" I want. Here the answer:

```
>>> K = [ ]
>>> K.append([ ])
>>> K.append([ ]) 
>>> K[0].append[A]
>>> K[0].append[C]
>>> K[1].append[B]
>>> K[1].append[D]
```

So, if I want to select the element A:

```
>>> K[0][0]
```

And the element B:

```
>>> K[1][0]
```

Comment: `K=[[A, C], [B, D]]` should also work.  This is a list of lists.  Lists can contain any mixture of elements, e.g. `[[A],[C,B,D]]`, [[A, C],[B,D, None]]`.